# Javascript error when running on different pages

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a standalone form. My issue is when I run the form standalone it runs fine but when the form code is included in some other page where it is supposed to be displayed it shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at submit:10
```

I have tried debugging it from last few hours but still not able to find the exact issue. could someone please point out where the mistake might be. It could be some small error but it will be really helpful if you could point it out.

Both the forms are these: [Standalone form](https://simrec.custhelp.com/ci/documents/detail/2/RMR_India_Campaign_Reg) and [form included in a page](http://india.simge.edu.sg/)

Comment: why post links to external pages, add your code to the question for those who wish to read your code instead of debugging it (Oh, and don't ask for your colleagues to upvote an obviously bad question)

Comment: I posted the external link because I have checked the code thoroughly and I believe there must be issue somewhere in the page where form has been included. Since it is a lot of code so I posted link to the page itself.

Comment: That is complete nonsense, the error line which is being shown is giving a good indication that it is part of the submit action, and that it is requesting a value from an html element which wasn't found. So either you show the javascript function that is attached to the submit, and a small form which can reproduce this error, or this is some form of getting views on your pages (there is a specific close reason for questions which say my code isn't working, but fail to include the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you load your page you will see an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: field is not defined
```

That is because **field** is defined here:

```
https://simrec.custhelp.com/rnt/rnw/javascript/enduser.js
```

which is not included in the other page. You are using **new field()** in your code without having it defined. Fix that and the rest could work if it's working in the standalone form.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't completely solve my problem but provided a good direction. Keep up the good work.